# Chrome flickering on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, kde

Kubuntu 20.04

Today, Chrome started flicking in the upper left corner. The distortions are visible all the time on DevTools, and most of the time whatever's in upper left flickers as well, whether DevTools are open or not.

Among some other things, today I was messing around with themes and installing QtCurves and Kvantum, though I have absolutely no idea whether Chrome started producing these artifacts at some point during the installation process, or while I was doing some other things. Changing all KDE theming back to normal did not help any bit.

Chrome build:  84.0.4147.135 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)

Chromium behaves exactly the same. Firefox's just fine.

[LINK to a video showing the flickering process.](https://dump.video/i/HcoBPj.mp4)

## Update

Disabling hardware acceleration removes flickering, though as of now I'm not exactly sure what all the implications of switching it off are, so I'd still like to resolve this problem some other way.

Comment: What happens if you disable hardware acceleration and restart the browser?

Comment: I did exactly that. Added an update to the main post.

Comment: There's no real ramifications for turning it off. HA doesn't work well in Linux anyhow and causes bugs like you experienced. You can still watch HD video just as well. Amusingly, you must have added the edit at just about the same second I was hitting the enter button. Anyhow, unless you hear otherwise, just leave it off - it's fine disabled. I disable it by default just to avoid the potential bugs cropping up. You can search the keywords and read more about it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll read about it. My CPU's Ryzen 3900xt, so I'd assume it'll be just fine with some WebGL stuff as well, hopefully.
Feel free to write it as a response and I'll accept it, if you wish. If you don't, I guess I'll write one myself.

Comment: I tossed up a quick answer with a recent link that explains it in more detail, should you be interested in knowing more about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer for this one is short and simple. Disable Hardware Acceleration and restart your browser for it to take effect.

Hardware Acceleration is when the browser lets some of the executing code run on the GPU, thus removing the burden from your CPU. Basically, it lets your video card take over some of the tasks.

The thing is, it doesn't actually work well with Linux, if at all. Even if you try to patch it, it doesn't work well - again, if at all.

As this one is about Chrome/Chromium, we can explain it fairly easily:

> Google says it has no plans to enable Chrome hardware acceleration on
> Linux — not even as an experimental option.

Source: [OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/10/hardware-acceleration-chrome-linux)

So, the next obvious question is, "If it's not working, or even really enabled properly, why is there an option in the Linux version and why is it enabled by default?"

The answer to that is, "Your guess is as good as mine."

If you're really bent on trying, and accepting the resultant bugs, you can try to [patch](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/532294) it but I've not seen it work well nor make any appreciable difference.

**NOTE:** Hardware Acceleration is the culprit (with browser bugs) so frequently that it's my default suggestion for things like this. It's the solution more often than not.